# How do I restore my parallel Whatsapp from backup after skipping the restore option?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Am using whatsapp parallel i passed this place. I still have my last back up in my fone. How can I access it back? And restore my last messages

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally skipped, then uninstall and install again.
note:

1. Whatsapp recognizes its installation by phone number. So if you wish to restore backup from a different number then sorry, it won't work.
2. In case both backups are from same phone number, you need to find and move whatsapp\database folder or com.whatsapp folder in \android folder in the root of storage from source to same location on target device.
3. Then install whatsapp and during installtion it will ask if you wish to restore previous messages from backup, say "yes".
4. If it does not find, either the location is incorrect or backup is not created using same phone number/key.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok would try it again

Comment: Mark as solution if that worked for you! Thanks!